# Использование Ninject при подключении к БД

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться, изучаю mvc и наткнулся на вот такой вот пример :

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Test.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(Test.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace Test.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;
    using System.Configuration;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<DataClasses1DataContext>().ToMethod(c => new DataClasses1DataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString));
            kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<SqlRepository>().InRequestScope();
        }        
    }
}
```

Так вот пока нашел нужный `WebActivator` день потерял, можно ли обойтись как-то иначе ? чем данный пример ? Может сейчас как-то иначе это делается, потому как пример по mvc3 думаю уже устарел. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный опус призван показать ход моих мыслей и опущено много деталей и проверок для упрощения.

Не совсем понятно что вы хотите в итоге получить, но с данной конфигурацией у вас получается при каждом разрешении зависимости (DataClasses1DataContext) создается новый экземпляр контекста, которому в качестве аргумента конструктора передается строка подключения взятая из конфигурации приложения (*.config). В целом решение как решение, хотя я наверное все таки бы конфигурацию вынес бы в отдельный тип и обозначил интерфейсом:

```
IConfigurationProvider
{
    GetConcreteConnectionString();
}
```

Ну и соответственно его реализация

```
ConfigurationProvider : IConfigurationProvider
{
    // Желательно приделать поле и хранить там полученную строку
    public GetConcreteConnectionString() => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

А в конструкторе контекста принимал бы уже IConfigurationProvider:

```
DataClasses1DataContext : DbContext
{
     internal DataClasses1DataContext(IConfigurationProvider provider) 
         : base(provider.GetConcreteConnectionString())
     {

     }
}
```

А биндинги обозначил бы примерно так:

```
kernel.Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().To<ConfigurationProvider>().InSingletonScope();
/* Здесь нужно быть внимательным и как по мне лучше время жизни контролировать с использование 
расширения Ninject NamedScope на тот случай если в последующем вы решите 
использовать этот набор типов в другом формате приложения (WinForms || WPF) */
kernel.Bind<DataClasses1DataContext>().ToSelf();
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<SqlRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваши мысли и предложения

Comment: @Ethernets Рад был помочь